# Looking for an algorithm to generate a flat 2D map

Tags: algorithm, random, 2d, parameterized

I'm not sure if "traditional" random noise-based height-map generation is what I need, because what I want to end up with is a very simple map consisting of two types of region.

The end result I want is some very simple geometry dividing 'land' areas from 'sea' areas, and determining if a point is wet or dry.

Ideally it should all be procedural, rather than based off pre-rendered height-maps, as I want the map to be randomly generated and somewhat parameterised.

Closest examples I can think of are the map-generators in the *SimCity* and *Civilisation* series, but simplified right down to 2D with a feel of *Defcon*.

Comment: Perlin noise (or some other "fractal" landscape generation), followed by a threshold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:
Start at any point.  Declare it height 0 (beach).  Recursively visit each adjacent point North, East, South, and West ala a flood fill passing the current node's height.  Add or subtract some parameterized, random value (say -2 to 2).  Clamp the values at min and max overall values (say -5 and 20).  Recurse through your map size ignoring previously visited nodes.  You now have a fairly contiguous 2D height map.  Negative height is wet.  You can play with how much the height changes per node and the min/max overall values to get more or less land - ocean's and continents vs archipelago's, etc.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I wasn't going to go for a grid-based map, although I suppose I could do for the sake of generation.

Comment: Remember, you could always take these generated heights and turn them into a 3D mesh rather easily if need be.  You stated you wanted a 2D feel similiar to Civ.  That's grid based if I remember correctly, with some fanciness thrown on top.